# Illegal offset type

Tags: php, arrays, file-upload

I am having trouble uploading a file through php.  I check the file type at the beginning of the process and I get an error.

This is the error I am getting:

> Warning: Illegal offset type in
>   /balblabla/DBfunctions.inc.php on line
>   183

This is the printed out $_FILES var

> > Array ( [Picture] => Array ( [name] =>
> >     JPG.jpg [type] => image/jpeg
> >     [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpHlrNY8 [error]
> >     => 0 [size] => 192221 ) )

Here is the segment of code I am using that is giving me issues:

```
function checkFile($file, $type)
{
    if( in_array($_FILES[$file]['type'], $type) ){    //   <---  LINE 183
        return true;
    }//if
    return false;
} // end checkFile()
```

This is the line of code that calls the function

> if( checkFile( $_FILES['Picture'], array("image/jpeg") ) == true  ){
>   //do stuff
>   }// end if

I have used this piece of code on dozens of websites on my own server so i am guessing that this is some different configuration option.  How can i modify my code so that it works on this different server?

Comment: Just a minor suggestion, you do not have to check this expression `checkFile(...) == true`, just do `if (checkFile(...))` if it returns the value *true*, your *do stuff* will be executed

Answer (score 9):

You are passing an array, not a string/integer index to your `checkFile` function.

To fix this, make one of the following to changes:

Change checkfile so that it uses the array passed in to do the checking, thusly:

```
if( in_array($file['type'], $type) )
```

OR change the code that calls this function so that it passes the name of the file to use as an index rather than the file array, thusly:

```
if( checkFile('Picture', array("image/jpeg") ) == true )
```

Either change will work.

Answer (score 2):

In `checkFile()` replace `$_FILES[$file]` with `$file`. You're indexing `$_FILES` array twice.