# WARNING Illegal string offset 'file' on line number 19

Tags: php, arrays

simple array giving error.

WARNING Illegal string offset 'file' on line number 19

any help will be great

```
<?php
  //    $someffdd is output of print_r

$someffdd="Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => 2Pcs-font-b-Mini-b-font-font-b-Couple-b-font-Lover-Animal-DIY-Resin-Fairy-32-185x215.jpg
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpwhglrk
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 8713
        )

)";

            foreach((array) $someffdd as $value ) {


    $jkgkgff=$value['file'];

echo $jkgkgff;
}

?>
```

tried all sort of combination but nothing is error free . i want to output name value

Comment: It will not work properly because your value is actually an output of an array.

Comment: @L.Herrera yes it is print_r output

Comment: @hareom Can you add your code as a snipit please? this will be the seventh wizzywig tool on your tool bar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Illegal offset type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188456/illegal-offset-type)

Comment: @dalelandry adding

Comment: @dalelandry php it does notallow

Comment: @rickdenhaan actually i am saving ajax request with file_put_contents and print_r saves output in text file but json_encode,json_decode,var_dump nothing works .text file is empty but print_r works

Comment: How do you write the array to the text file? You should be able to use something like `file_put_contents("file.txt", json_encode($_FILES));`

Comment: @rickdenhaan tried again .blank

Comment: @rickdenhaan thanks for your help. u have guided me in right direction. will solve mostly. Good day friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot parse the output of `print_r()` (or `var_dump()`) back into an array in PHP. So `(array)$someffdd` will fail, and you'll be looping through a string (i.e. `$value` will be 'A' the first time, then 'r', then another 'r', then 'a' and so on, until it reaches the final ')').

If you cannot change the source of your `$someffdd` to something PHP can parse using `json_encode()`, `serialize()` or `var_export()`, you can either use regular expressions to match the `name` section of the string, or use some `strpos()/substr()` wizardry:

```
$matches = [];
preg_match("/\[name\] => (.*)\n/", $someffdd, $matches);
$name = $matches[1];

$position = strpos($someffdd, '[name] => ') + 10;
$section = substr($someffdd, $position);
$eol = strpos($section, "\n");
$name = substr($section, 0, $eol);
```

Comment: thanks.can i want to see what my code is generating so i was using print)r. is there anyway i can generate exactly same as print_r is adding unnecessary array

Comment: If you want to read along with your output, I suggest outputting JSON. That's pretty human-readable and can be parsed by PHP: `echo json_encode($my_array);` -> `$my_array = json_decode('json string');`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where this array comes from, but when the array has proper string values it works without issue by simply calling on the key value parent/child:
*Your array in its current state is not properly configured.

```
$someffdd = Array (
    "file" => Array (
        "name" => "2Pcs-font-b-Mini-b-font-font-b-Couple-b-font-Lover-Animal-DIY-Resin-Fairy-32-185x215.jpg",
        "type" => "application/octet-stream",
        "tmp_name" => "/tmp/phpwhglrk",
        "error" => 0,
        "size" => 8713
    )

);
//with proper array getting name is simple:
var_dump($someffdd["file"]["name"]);
```